# Rxjs search in Angular

Tags: angular, search, rxjs

I created an rxjs search for a hiring company, but I got rejected for the following reason:
-performance issue on a bigger data set.
-bugs

**My question is how can I make this code better for the next time if I have similar task?**

brands =  These should be populated from the brand property from the collection of products.

> The search should match using the name, description and brand
> properties.
>
> - The search should not fire unless a minimum of three characters have been typed.
> - The search should only fire a maximum of once per 400 milliseconds.
>
> If searching for “xxx” with the brand selected as “xxx” and In Stock, then only products matching all three filters

```
const stackoverflowFilter = (filter: ISearch) => {
  return (product: IProducts): boolean => {
    return ((
      (
        (product.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(filter.input.toLowerCase()) !== -1) ||
        product.description.toLowerCase().indexOf(filter.input.toLowerCase()) !== -1 ||
        product.brand.toLowerCase().indexOf(filter.input.toLowerCase()) !== -1) &&
      product.brand.toLowerCase().indexOf(filter.select.toLowerCase()) !== -1 &&
      (filter.radio === 'all' ? true : filter.radio === 'in-stock' ? product.quantity > 0 : product.quantity === 0)
    )
    )
  };
};

export interface ISearch { input: string; select: string; radio: string }



> public getStackoverflow(): Observable<Stackoverflow[]> {
>         return of([
>           {
>             id: "1",
>             name: "This is just test data",
>             price: "89.9",
>             description: "test data",
>             brand: "stackoverflow",
>             quantity: 4
>           }....])}



 this.stackoverflow$ = this.service.getStackoverflow();

    this.stackoverflow$.pipe(
      tap((prod) => {
        this.stackoverflow = prod;
        this.brands = this.stackoverflow.map(({ brand }) => brand).reduce((prev, cur) => {
          if (prev.indexOf(cur) < 0) prev.push(cur);
          return prev;
        }, []);
      }),
      concatMap(() =>
        this.search$.pipe(
          debounceTime(400),
          distinctUntilChanged(),
          switchMap((search: string) =>
            iif(() => search.length >= 3,
              this.stackoverflow$.pipe(
                map(products => stackoverflow.filter(stackoverflowFilter(this.filter))),
                distinctUntilChanged((curr, prev) => curr === prev),
              ),
              this.stackoverflow$.pipe(
                filter(() => search.length === 0),
              )
            )
          )
        ))
    ).subscribe(
      products => { this.stackoverflow= stackoverflow; },
      (err) => throwError(err)
    );
```

Comment: You'll probably have a better response in [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thanks I will try there.